# Win10 file Explorer cannot remember to maximize

Tags: windows, visual-c++, windows-shell

I use ShellExecuteEx open the Explorer,it can remember other size but maxsize. Remembering the size means i can open the Explorer as the size when i close it

Comment: Have you tried using the `SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED` flag in the `nShow` member of the passed `SHELLEXECUTEINFO` structure?

Comment: I hope it can remember the size when i closed it instead of maximizing every time it is opened. Now,it can remember other size. But I maximize  it ,then close it,  it will  open as default size instead of max size.